# SUMIFS Values from non consecutive Column Cells

Tags: sumifs

I need tu sum several cells that are separated one from another, these cells are

C3,F3,I3,L3,O3,R3,U3,X3,AA3,AD3,AG3,AJ3,AM3,AP3,AS3,AV3,AY3,BB3,BE3,BH3,BK3,BN3,BQ3,BT3,BW3,BZ3,CC3,CF3,CI3,CL3,CO3

if this other cells $C$1,$F$1,$I$1,$L$1,$O$1,$R$1,$U$1,$X$1,$AA$1,$AD$1,$AG$1,$AJ$1,$AM$1,$AP$1,$AS$1,$AV$1,$AY$1,$BB$1,$BE$1,$BH$1,$BK$1,$BN$1,$BQ$1,$BT$1,$BW$1,$BZ$1,$CC$1,$CF$1,$CI$1,$CL$1,$CO$1

that are on the same column but different row are >= to certain number given and <= to other given number, but it returns #Value, can somebody help me find out what am I doing wrong?

This is the function i am writing:

=SUMIFS((C3,F3,I3,L3,O3,R3,U3,X3,AA3,AD3,AG3,AJ3,AM3,AP3,AS3,AV3,AY3,BB3,BE3,BH3,BK3,BN3,BQ3,BT3,BW3,BZ3,CC3,CF3,CI3,CL3,CO3),($C$1,$F$1,$I$1,$L$1,$O$1,$R$1,$U$1,$X$1,$AA$1,$AD$1,$AG$1,$AJ$1,$AM$1,$AP$1,$AS$1,$AV$1,$AY$1,$BB$1,$BE$1,$BH$1,$BK$1,$BN$1,$BQ$1,$BT$1,$BW$1,$BZ$1,$CC$1,$CF$1,$CI$1,$CL$1,$CO$1),">="&B55,($C$1,$F$1,$I$1,$L$1,$O$1,$R$1,$U$1,$X$1,$AA$1,$AD$1,$AG$1,$AJ$1,$AM$1,$AP$1,$AS$1,$AV$1,$AY$1,$BB$1,$BE$1,$BH$1,$BK$1,$BN$1,$BQ$1,$BT$1,$BW$1,$BZ$1,$CC$1,$CF$1,$CI$1,$CL$1,$CO$1),"<="&C55)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain, but it looks like the problem here is that SUMIFS requires arguments to be expressed in continuous-range form, e.g. A3:CO3. It looks like you're trying to work with every third column in the dataset, yes? As far as I can tell, this is best (only?) done as an array function, so that you can tell it to filter on "every third column."

Enter this in the cell, then press CTRL+SHIFT+Enter (CSE) to evaluate it as an array function:

`=SUM(($A$1:$CO$1>=B55)*($A$1:$CO$1<=C55)*(MOD(COLUMN(A3:CO3),3)=0)*(A3:CO3))`

You'll also need to hit CSE every time you evaluate or change it. There's a decent tutorial for array functions at https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7, which may help if you're unfamiliar with them.